# I have wrongly transferred 0.00184426 BTC, request please help to return it back to my wallet

Tags: transactions

I have wrongly transferred 0.00184426 BTC to address (TN3W4H6rK2ce4vX9YnFQHwKENnHjoxb3m9) request you to pls help me to return it back to my account.

Answer (score -1):

Did you possibly convert your BTC to something called BTCTRON?  I don't know what this is (apparently some type of wrapped Bitcoin token on the TRON blockchain), but you can supposedly convert it back to BTC again with no fees.  See  https://support.poloniex.com/hc/en-us/articles/360054846854-Using-Bitcoin-on-TRON-FAQ

The  reason I think this is what happened is that the receiving address you gave looks like it's the one that you would have used to swap your BTC for BTCTRON.

Comment: Why the downvote?